# How do I create multilevel modal popups in php with jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, modal-dialog

Getting more precise, i want to generate modal popup(call it A) and in that modal popup i have a button, on click of that button i want to invoke another modal popup(B),during which modal popup A should persist in back. When i close modal popup B, A should get active.

Comment: What kind of popups? Actual popup windows? The ones that get blocked by a popup blocker? Or do you want something like 'modal lightboxes'?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Take a look at the qTip2 modal dialog jquery plugin. See demo here. http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/modal

Comment: May be [Simplemodal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/#examples)?

Comment: Thank you all of you. To great extent it was helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **[jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)**. It has native support for dialog-on-dialog.

Take a look at this [simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/Qrqbq/).

Comment: Thanks a lot it helped me, will make certain changes like will add mask and set width. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [JQuery UI Dialogs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) - you can have multiple ones open at once, modal or not, with buttons or without... very good controls and should be what you're looking for.

You can access events like open, close and focus (amongst others) on a dialog to take care of doing different things in response to different actions, and there are methods to open/close/get focus etc - so it should have everything you've asked for.

Answer (score 0):

A basic example using jQuery UI dialogs:

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ 
    modal: true,
    buttons: [
        {
            text: "Open Next",
            click: function() { 
                $( ".selector" ).dialog({
                    modal: true
                });
            }
        }
    ] 
});
```